# How to maintain Pandas DataFrame index order when using stack/unstack?

Tags: python, pandas

**Example One:**
Notice the index order of the given Pandas DataFrame `df`:

```
>>> df
              A  B
first second      
zzz   z       2  4
      a       1  5
aaa   z       6  3
      a       7  8
```

After using the `stack` and `unstack` methods on the given `df` DataFrame object, the index is automatically sorted lexicographically (alphabetically) so that one loses the original order of the rows.

```
>>> df.unstack().stack()
              A  B
first second      
aaa   a       7  8
      z       6  3
zzz   a       1  5
      z       2  4
```

Is it possible to maintain the original ordering after the `unstack/stack` operations above?

According to official documentation [reshaping-by-stacking-and-unstacking](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-stacking-and-unstacking):

> Notice that the stack and unstack methods implicitly sort the index levels involved. Hence a call to stack and then unstack, or viceversa, will result in a sorted copy of the original DataFrame or Series

**Example Two:**

```
>>> dfu = df.unstack()
>>> dfu
         A      Z   
second   a  z   a  z
first               
aaa      7  6   8  3
zzz      1  2   5  4
```

If the original index is perserved we need `dfu` like so:

```
>>> dfu
             A      Z   
    second   a  z   a  z
    first               
    zzz      1  2   5  4
    aaa      7  6   8  3
```

What I'm looking for is a solution that could be used to revert the index order based on the original dataframe after an `unstack()` or `stack()` method has been called.

Comment: you can keep a copy of the original index and reindex to that...otherwise I don't think so.

Comment: For an example, like above, where the original DataFrame's index labels match the resulting DataFrame's labels this could work. I'm looking for a solution where this might not be the case.

Answer (score 9):

You can keep a copy of the original `index` and [reindex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to that, thanks Andy Hayden.

Demo:

```
#              A  B
#first second      
#zzz   z       2  4
#      a       1  5
#aaa   z       6  3
#      a       7  8

print df.index
#MultiIndex(levels=[[u'aaa', u'zzz'], [u'a', u'z']],
#           labels=[[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0]],
#           names=[u'first', u'second'])

#set index to variable
index = df.index

#stack and unstack
df = df.unstack().stack()
print df
#              A  B
#first second      
#aaa   a       7  8
#      z       6  3
#zzz   a       1  5
#      z       2  4
#              A  B

df = df.reindex(index)
print df
#              A  B
#first second      
#zzz   z       2  4
#      a       1  5
#aaa   z       6  3
#      a       7  8
```

Comment: Cool, this works for `df.unstack().stack()` case, but lets say you have `df.unstack()` only, you'll need to run `df.unstack().reindex(df.index.get_level_values(0))` to make reindexing work.

Comment: @AtlasStrategic This seems what I need but it's giving me 'TypeError: Expected tuple, got str' for the call to `reindex`.